# What skill proficiencies do I get from multiclassing into Artificer?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, multi-classing, proficiency, artificer

I can't find the rules for multiclassing into Artificer.  My character is starting out with Rogue through level 3 and then going into Artificer, after which I will bounce back and forth.  Which *skill* proficiency do I get when I choose Artificer for multiclassing?

Rogues normally get 4 and artificers normally get 2, but I doubt I would get all of those.  Also, I don't really care about armor or weapon proficiency because everything I need for this build I get from Rogue and a lot of the tool proficiencies overlap.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Are you asking about the artificer from [this 2019 UA](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf)?

Answer (score 17):

### You gain no *skill* proficiencies by multiclassing into Artificer

Per the Artificer class description on [page 54 of *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/character-creation-class-artificer#OptionalRuleMulticlassing) (or in [Appendix D](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wgte/artificer) of the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron)*, there is an optional rule addendum on how multiclassing into artificer works if you're using the multiclassing rules:

> **Optional Rule: Multiclassing**
>
> If your group uses the optional rule on multiclassing in the Player’s Handbook [p. 163], here’s what you need to know if you choose artificer as one of your classes.
>
> **Ability Score Minimum.** As a multiclass character, you must have at least an Intelligence score of 13 to take a level in this class, or to take a level in another class if you are already an artificer.
>
> **Proficiencies Gained.** If artificer isn’t your initial class, here are the proficiencies you gain when you take your first level as an artificer: light armor, medium armor, shields, thieves’ tools, tinker’s tools.
>
> **Spell Slots.** Add half your levels (rounded up) in the artificer class to the appropriate levels from other classes to determine your available spell slots.

These are also reproduced on the DnDBeyond [class page for the artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#OptionalRuleMulticlassing). Unfortunately for your multiclass, you don't appear to gain any extra skill proficiencies by going into artificer; only the tool proficiences for thieves' and tinker's tools.

The original [UA Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf) from 2017 doesn't include multiclassing rules (as NautArch notes in comments, UA classes normally don't) so if you're still working from that version, that might be why you can't find these rules. Multiclassing rules were  first added in the [early 2019 UA version](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf) (as a sidebar at the end of the document) and finalised with the release of *E:RftLW*.